# How to Set Store Config (system configuration)

Tags: magento-1, system.xml, system-configuration

We can get system configuration values using

```
Mage::getStoreConfig($xmlPath);
```

But how can we set such configuration field programatically? I would expect some method like

```
Mage::setStoreConfig($xmlPath, $val);
```

But the closest thing I'm seeing is

```
Mage::app()
    ->getStore()
    ->setConfig($xmlPath, $val);
    ->save();
```

But this is not updating the config value. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
/*
*turns notice on
*/
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('design/head/demonotice', '1', 'default', 0);
/*
*turns notice off
*/
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('design/head/demonotice', '0', 'default', 0);
```

```
class Mage_Core_Model_Config
{

    /**
     * Save config value to DB
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $value
     * @param string $scope
     * @param int $scopeId
     * @return Mage_Core_Store_Config
     */
    public function saveConfig($path, $value, $scope = 'default', $scopeId = 0)
    {
        $resource = $this->getResourceModel();
        $resource->saveConfig(rtrim($path, '/'), $value, $scope, $scopeId);

        return $this;
    }


}
```

Comment: nice.. thank you!!